# Keyboard aware scroll view Android issue

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I've created a react native project using Expo XDE (xde-2.19.3) with a few `TextInputs` on the screen. Im using `KeyboardAwareScrollView` to scroll the inputs from under the keyboard into view and works fine on iOS but does not work on Android. Hope that makes sense.

Looked at the `KeyboardAwareScrollView` docs and saw that I need to configure `AndroidManifest.xml` but it seems that Expo has already sorted this out: https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/master/template-files/android/AndroidManifest.xml

However I'm still not able to get this working on Android...

What could I be missing?

```
render() {
    return (
      <KeyboardAwareScrollView
        enableOnAndroid='true'
        enableAutoAutomaticScrol='true'
        keyboardOpeningTime={0}
      >
      <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.subcontainer}>
          <View style={styles.form}>
              <TextInput
                ref='NoduleCountInput'
                onFocus={() => this.onFocus()}
                onBlur={() => this.onBlur()}
                keyboardType='phone-pad'
                returnKeyType='done'
                placeholder='Test'
                style={styles.field}
              />
              <TextInput
                ref='NoduleCountInput'
                onFocus={() => this.onFocus()}
                onBlur={() => this.onBlur()}
                keyboardType='phone-pad'
                returnKeyType='done'
                placeholder='Test'
                style={styles.field}
              />
              <TextInput
                ref='NoduleCountInput'
                onFocus={() => this.onFocus()}
                onBlur={() => this.onBlur()}
                keyboardType='phone-pad'
                returnKeyType='done'
                placeholder='Test'
                style={styles.field}
              />
              <TextInput
                ref='NoduleCountInput'
                onFocus={() => this.onFocus()}
                onBlur={() => this.onBlur()}
                keyboardType='phone-pad'
                returnKeyType='done'
                placeholder='Test'
                style={styles.field}
              />
              <TextInput
                ref='NoduleCountInput'
                onFocus={() => this.onFocus()}
                onBlur={() => this.onBlur()}
                keyboardType='phone-pad'
                returnKeyType='done'
                placeholder='Test'
                style={styles.field}
              />
              <TextInput
                ref='NoduleCountInput'
                onFocus={() => this.onFocus()}
                onBlur={() => this.onBlur()}
                keyboardType='phone-pad'
                returnKeyType='done'
                placeholder='Test'
                style={styles.field}
              />
              <TextInput
                ref='NoduleCountInput'
                onFocus={() => this.onFocus()}
                onBlur={() => this.onBlur()}
                keyboardType='phone-pad'
                returnKeyType='done'
                placeholder='Test'
                style={styles.field}
              />
            </View>
         </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I tried the above solution for cross platform support but its not correct. The right and complete solution if you want the focus with automatic scrolling to TextInput to work is to set parameters as follows:

```
<KeyboardAwareScrollView
  enableOnAndroid={true}
  enableAutomaticScroll={(Platform.OS === 'ios')}
>
...
</KeyboardAwareScrollView>
```

This is because enableAutomaticScroll is enabled by default and it mixes up with the native Android behaviour to give unexpected results. So set this field to false when Platform is Android.

And yes also set the following in `app.json` without which it will not work.

```
"androidStatusBar": {
  "backgroundColor": "#000000"
}
```

Comment: Yep this is what I ended up doing. so you need to set `androidStatusBar` for some weird reason.

Comment: yeah that worked but I dont use default status bar so it makes my margins ugly :(

Comment: I am using react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view and recently encountered the same problem on android. I solved it by disabling automatic scroll for android without adding androidStatusBar change.

Comment: It is really wired, I also just added "androidStatusBar": { "backgroundColor": "#000000" } it started working properly. Event transperant or other colors won;t worked. 

Answer (score 14):

I tried the other solutions and they didn't work for me, but finally I manage to make it work by using the following code:

```
 <KeyboardAwareScrollView enableOnAndroid={true} extraHeight={130} extraScrollHeight={130}>
  ...
</KeyboardAwareScrollView>
```

Comment: extraHeight works but it gives extra space at the bottom of the page when keyboard is open is there a way to handle that too?

Answer (score 7):

This is how I fixed it:

In `app.json` I set:

```
"androidStatusBar": {
  "backgroundColor": "#000000"
}
```

This fixed the issue, I don't know how but it did. So will leave this here just incase someone else finds it useful.

Comment: It is the only thing worked. I tried almost all possible solutions, even though there is no relation between backgroundColor and scroll 

Comment: @RohitParte this question is very old I'm sure there's a better way of doing things now :)

Answer (score 4):

For expo managed workflow,

1. Go to `app.json` add this:

```
   "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "softwareKeyboardLayoutMode": "pan" // add this line. 
    },
```

As mention in docs with this line:

> First, Android natively has this feature, you can easily enable it by setting windowSoftInputMode in AndroidManifest.xml

So to do this, we set it in `app.json` , as stated [here](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/config/app/#softwarekeyboardlayoutmode)

Then in component:

```
 <KeyboardAwareScrollView  
     extraScrollHeight={100} // (when scroll)to have extra height between keyboard and text input 
     enableOnAndroid={true}
     extraHeight={80} // make some height so the keyboard wont cover other component
     contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1}} // make the scrollView full screen 
> 
   // other stuff
</KeyboardAwareScrollView >
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <KeyboardAwareScrollView
        enableOnAndroid={true}
        extraScrollHeight={90}
        >
       <Content>
        <View></View>
       </Content>
<KeyboardAwareScrollView/>
```

Comment: Can you add some context around your answer, and how it fixes the problem?

Comment: in the place of Content you can replace your form or whatever you want just cover those code with main component which is 
import KeyboardAwareScrollView from 'KeyboardAwareScrollView';
<KeyboardAwareScrollView
        enableOnAndroid={true}
        extraScrollHeight={90}
        >                                                                                                                             
<KeyboardAwareScrollView/>

Answer (score 1):

for me I was facing this issue on Android (react-native 0.62.2). iOS was working perfectly. I found that `adjustResize` flag in Android manifest was the culprit. I removed it and it started working

**Before**

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan|adjustResize"
```

**After**

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan"
```

**Warning**

*I don't know what side effects it will cause in future.*

Comment: Other ReactNative libraries need this flag

Comment: He is using expo

Answer (score 1):

Go to AndroidManifest.xml and make sure the attribute.

-->  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

Comment: he is asking for expo

Answer (score -4):

Use

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"></activity>
```

in your `Manifest`

Comment: This actually doesn't solve the problem at all.
Actually the docs are stating that it's better to use "adjustPan"