# How to set the textinput box above the Keyboard while entering the input field in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, textbox, keyboard-events, textinput

I am using `react-native TextInput` component. Here I need to show the `InputBox` above the keyboard if the user clicks on the textInput field.

**1. Keyboard avoiding view**

1. Here it shows some empty space below the input box.
2. Manually I need to scroll up the screen to see the input field which I was given in the text field.
3. Input box section is hiding while placing the mouse inside the input box.

**2. react-native-Keyboard-aware-scroll-view**

1. It shows some empty space below the input box.
2. `ScrollView` is reset to the top of the page after I moving to the next input box.

Here I set the [Keyboard-aware-scroll-view](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view) inside the `ScrollView` component.

My example code is:

```js
<SafeAreaView>
    <KeyboardAvoidingView>
        <ScrollView>
            <Text>Name</Text>
            <AutoTags
                //required
                suggestions={this.state.suggestedName}
                handleAddition={this.handleAddition}
                handleDelete={this.handleDelete}
                multiline={true}
                placeholder="TYPE IN"
                blurOnSubmit={true}
                style={styles.style}
            />
        </ScrollView>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
</SafeAreaView>
```

Comment: try setting behviour for KeyboardAvoidingView, and make sure your contianer view style is flex

Comment: I have set behaviour = 'padding' style  = {{flex:1 }}for KeyboardAvoidingView.                         <KeyboardAvoidingView style = {{flex:1}}behavior='padding'>
        <View>
          <Text style>NAME </Text>
          <View>
            <TextInput> placeholder="TYPE IN"/>
          </View>
        </View>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>

Comment: I need this like behaviour in react native. When moving to text input box the keyboard opened and dismissed after return.https://github.com/Just-/UIViewController-KeyboardAnimation

Comment: can you try taking out the `<View>` tags and place just one outside the `<KeyboardAvoidingView>`?

Comment: not sure why you rolled back my edits. it would certainly help if you can place the code in your description of the issue.

Comment: @kenmistry I have added my example code. It will not shows the inputText box above the keyboard. I want to scrollup to see which input I am giving in the text box. Autotags has the same properties of the TextInput box.

Answer (score 33):

You can use a scrollview and put all components inside the scrollview and add `automaticallyAdjustKeyboardInsets` property to scrollview.it will solve your problem.

**`automaticallyAdjustKeyboardInsets` Controls whether the ScrollView should automatically adjust its contentInset and
scrollViewInsets when the Keyboard changes its size. The default value is false.**

```
<ScrollView automaticallyAdjustKeyboardInsets={true}>
    {allChildComponentsHere}
    <View style={{ height: 30 }} /> // Added some extra space to last element
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 16):

Give your TextInput a position: absolute styling and change its position using the height returned by the keyboardDidShow and keyboardDidHide events.

Here is a modification of the Keyboard example from the React Native [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboard) for demonstration:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Keyboard, TextInput } from 'react-native';

class Example extends Component {
    state = {
        keyboardOffset: 0,
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener(
            'keyboardDidShow',
            this._keyboardDidShow,
        );
        this.keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener(
            'keyboardDidHide',
            this._keyboardDidHide,
        );
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
        this.keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
    }

    _keyboardDidShow(event) {
        this.setState({
            keyboardOffset: event.endCoordinates.height,
        })
    }

    _keyboardDidHide() {
        this.setState({
            keyboardOffset: 0,
        })
    }

    render() {
        return <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <TextInput
                style={{
                    position: 'absolute',
                    width:    '100%',
                    bottom:   this.state.keyboardOffset,
                }}
                onSubmitEditing={Keyboard.dismiss}
            />
        </View>;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried with this. But it not worked as I expected in AutoTags

Comment: Hi, I am trying the code above, but I have noticed that the page content, which in my case is a `FlatList` jumps cuz of the `bottom: this.state.keyboardOffset`. Also, it seems that `event.endCoordinates.height` returns a higher value than the keyboard, cuz there is a gap between the `TextInput` and `Keyboard`.

Comment: @Yasir "absolute" positioned elements are relative to their containing view, which may differ in size from the device. If your TextInput is inside a container that is smaller than the device height, you need to account for difference in height between container and device. Here's a formula that worked for me to position a "Text" view directly above the keyboard:  `bottom: keyboardHeight - ((deviceHeight - containerHeight) / 2)`. I have a top and bottom bar, with my Text view in a container between, so I accounted for the diff between device height and my container.

Comment: dont do this, this cause layout laggy

Answer (score 14):

First of all, **You don't need any extra code for Android platform.** Only keep your inputs inside a `ScrollView`. Just use `KeyboardAvoidingView` to encapsulate the `ScrollView` for iOS platform.

Create a function such as below, which holds all the inputs

```js
renderInputs = () => {
    return (<ScrollView
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        style={{
            flex: 1,
        }}
        contentContainerStyle={{
            flexGrow: 1,
        }}>
        <Text>Enter Email</Text>
        <TextInput
            style={styles.text}
            underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
        />
    </ScrollView>)
}
```

Then render them inside the main view as below:

```js
{Platform.OS === 'android' ? (
    this.renderInputs()
) : (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding">
        {this.renderInputs()}
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
)}
```

Comment: You can use `KeyboardAvoidingView ` for Android as well. Just set `behavior="height"`.  No need for a render function.

Answer (score 11):

**Hooks version**

```js
const [keyboardOffset, setKeyboardOffset] = useState(0);
const onKeyboardShow = event => setKeyboardOffset(event.endCoordinates.height);
const onKeyboardHide = () => setKeyboardOffset(0);
const keyboardDidShowListener = useRef();
const keyboardDidHideListener = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
  keyboardDidShowListener.current = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardWillShow', onKeyboardShow);
  keyboardDidHideListener.current = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardWillHide', onKeyboardHide);

  return () => {
    keyboardDidShowListener.current.remove();
    keyboardDidHideListener.current.remove();
  };
}, []);
```

Comment: <TextInput style={{marginBottom:keyboardOffset}}/>

Comment: In my case `keyboardDidShow` & `keyboardDidHide` event worked.

Comment: For Typescript, you'll need to type the event and ref like so:

const onKeyboardShow = (event: { endCoordinates: { height: React.SetStateAction<number> } }) =>
    setKeyboardOffset(event.endCoordinates.height);
  const onKeyboardHide = () => setKeyboardOffset(0);
  const keyboardDidShowListener = useRef<EmitterSubscription>();
  const keyboardDidHideListener = useRef<EmitterSubscription>();

Answer (score 6):

you can use [KeyboardAvoidingView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboardavoidingview) as follows

```
if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
        return <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding">
            {this.renderChatInputSection()}
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    } else {
        return this.renderChatInputSection()
    }
```

Where `this.renderChatInputSection()`  will return the view like textinput for typing message. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Try this [react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view#readme) and remove ScrollView

Comment: It will show a space below the input box after entering the inputs

Comment: @seijn give it a style of `{flexGrow: 1}`

Answer (score 2):

For android you can set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` for `Activity` in `AndroidManifest` file, thus when the keyboard shows, your screen will resize and if you put the `TextInput` at the bottom of your screen, it will be keep above keyboard

Answer (score 2):

> write these two lines in your android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
> inside activity tag

`android:launchMode="singleTask" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan"`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view` caused similar issue in iOS. That's when I came across [react-native-keyboard-aware-view](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-keyboard-aware-view). Snippets are pretty much same.

```js
<KeyboardAwareView animated={true}>
  <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <ScrollView style={{flex: 1}}>
      <Text style={{fontSize: 20, color: '#FFFFFF'}}>A</Text>
      <Text style={{fontSize: 20, color: '#FFFFFF'}}>B</Text>
      <Text style={{fontSize: 20, color: '#FFFFFF'}}>C</Text>
      <Text style={{fontSize: 20, color: '#FFFFFF'}}>D</Text>
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
  <TouchableOpacity style={{height: 50, backgroundColor: 'transparent', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', alignSelf: 'stretch'}}>
    <Text style={{fontSize: 20, color: '#FFFFFF'}}>Submit</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
</KeyboardAwareView>
```

Hope it hepls.

Comment: Here it is not text. TextInput box which render from react-native autoTags

Answer (score 0):

You will definitely find this useful from

[Keyboard aware scroll view Android issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45466026/keyboard-aware-scroll-view-android-issue)

I really don't know why you have to add

> "androidStatusBar": {
>         "backgroundColor": "#000000"
>       }

for KeyboardawareScrollview to work

***Note*:don't forget to restart the project without the last step it might not work
enjoy!**

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem when I was working on my side project, and I solved it after tweaking KeyboardAvoidingView somewhat.
I published [my solution](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-keyboard-sticky-view) to npm, please give it a try and give me a feedback! [Demo on iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxiXV.gif)

Example Snippet

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import KeyboardStickyView from 'rn-keyboard-sticky-view';

const KeyboardInput = (props) => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');

  return (
    <KeyboardStickyView style={styles.keyboardView}>
      <TextInput
        value={value}
        onChangeText={setValue}
        onSubmitEditing={() => alert(value)}
        placeholder="Write something..."
        style={styles.input}
      />
    </KeyboardStickyView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  keyboardView: { ... },
  input: { ... }
});

export default KeyboardInput;
```

Answer (score 0):

I based my solution of @basbase solution.

My issue with his solution that it makes the TextInput jumps up without any regard for my overall view.

That wasn't what I wanted in my case, so I did as he suggested but with a small modification

Just give the parent View styling like this:

```
 <View 
             style={{
              flex: 1,
              bottom:   keyboardOffset,
          }}>
```

And it would work! the only issue is that if the keyboard is open and you scrolled down you would see the extra blank padding at the end of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

`flexGrow: 1` is the key.

Use it like below:

```
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.container}>
  <TextInput
    label="Note"
    value={currentContact.note}
    onChangeText={(text) => setAttribute("note", text)}
  />
</ScrollView>
```

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Install this package using `npm i react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view --save` then put your input like this:

```
<KeyboardAwareScrollView>
  <View>
    <TextInput />
  </View>
</KeyboardAwareScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `"softwareKeyboardLayoutMode": "pan"` to the app.json file under android:

```
"android": {
      "softwareKeyboardLayoutMode": "pan",
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

This is worked for me
Go to **AndroidManifest.xml**
Paste the below line inside the **activity** tag

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan"
```

Answer (score -1):

Best and Easy Way is to use Scroll View , It will Automatically take content Up and `TextInput` will not be hide,Can refer Below Code

```js
      <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
      <View>
        <View style={styles.commonView}>
          <Image source={firstNameIcon} style={{width: 25, height: 25}}></Image>
          <Text style={styles.commonTxt}>First Name</Text>
        </View>

        <TextInput
          onFocus={() => onFocus('firstName')}
          placeholder="First Name"
          style={styles.txtInput}
          onChangeText={(text) => onChangeText(text, 'firstName')}
          value={firstNameValue}
        />
      </View>
      <View>
        <View style={styles.commonView}>
          <Image source={LastNameIcon} style={{width: 25, height: 25}}></Image>
          <Text style={styles.commonTxt}>Last Name</Text>
        </View>

        <TextInput
          onFocus={() => onFocus('lastName')}
          placeholder="Last Name"
          style={styles.txtInput}
          onChangeText={(text) => onChangeText(text, 'lastName')}
          value={lastNameValue}
        />
      </View>
      <View>
        <View style={styles.commonView}>
          <Image source={callIcon} style={{width: 25, height: 25}}></Image>
          <Text style={styles.commonTxt}>Number</Text>
        </View>

        <TextInput
          onFocus={() => onFocus('number')}
          placeholder="Number"
          style={styles.txtInput}
          onChangeText={(text) => onChangeText(text, 'number')}
          value={numberValue}
        />
      </View>
      <View>
        <View style={styles.commonView}>
          <Image source={emailIcon} style={{width: 25, height: 25}}></Image>
          <Text style={styles.commonTxt}>Email</Text>
        </View>

        <TextInput
          onFocus={() => onFocus('email')}
          placeholder="Email"
          style={styles.txtInput}
          onChangeText={(text) => onChangeText(text, 'email')}
          value={emailValue}
        />
      </View>

      <View style={styles.viewSavebtn}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btn}>
          <Text style={styles.saveTxt}>Save</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score -1):

go to your Android>app>src>main> AndroidManifest.xml
write these 2 lines :

`android:launchMode="singleTop" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`

[image]