# TextInput got hides behind keyboard in react-native

Tags: react-native, user-interface, expo, textinput

I am creating chat UI in react native in which I want the first section (where the messages are shown) should be scrollable.

The `TextInput` should be at the bottom of screen and keyboard should be after it.

The  UI is similar to WhatsApp chat screen. But I'm unable to re-create that UI.

I have also tried `KeyboardAvoidingView` from `react-native` but it doesn't works for me like it do.

#### App.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  Alert,
  Dimensions,
  Platform,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";

import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";

const App = () => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState([]);

  
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "space-evenly",
        alignItems: "center",
        height: Dimensions.get("window").height,
        width: Dimensions.get("window").width,
      }}
    >
      <View
        style={{
          height: Dimensions.get("window").height * 0.8,
          backgroundColor: "lightgrey",
          width: Dimensions.get("window").width,
        }}
      >
        <ScrollView></ScrollView>
      </View>
      <View
        style={{
          height: Dimensions.get("window").height * 0.2,
          width: Dimensions.get("window").width,
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "row",
          justifyContent: "space-evenly",
          alignItems: "center",
          padding: 25,
        }}
      >
        <View style={{ flex: 4 }}>
          <TextInput placeholder="Type Message ....." />
        </View>
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Ionicons name="md-send" size={30} color="#0af" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I have added my code on [expo snack](https://snack.expo.io/@darkkiller/shallow-tortillas).

Comment: you must try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74210255/9412981)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have run into this issue several times while working on `react-native` projects. So I use another package to make it work. I have tested it on your `snack` and it works fine.

> The package is called `react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view`. It's
> a lightweight package with an unpacked size of just 10kB.

It has several useful props that you can use to adjust the component. Check it out [here](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view).

*Here is a link to the [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@ajinkabeer/shallow-tortillas) that I used to test your code.*

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  Alert,
  Dimensions,
  Platform,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view'


import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";

const App = () => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState([]);


  return (
    <KeyboardAwareScrollView
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "space-evenly",
        alignItems: "center",
        height: Dimensions.get("window").height,
        width: Dimensions.get("window").width,
      }}
    >
      <View
        style={{
          height: Dimensions.get("window").height * 0.8,
          backgroundColor: "lightgrey",
          width: Dimensions.get("window").width,
        }}
      >
        <ScrollView></ScrollView>
      </View>
      <View
        style={{
          height: Dimensions.get("window").height * 0.2,
          width: Dimensions.get("window").width,
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "row",
          justifyContent: "space-evenly",
          alignItems: "center",
          padding: 25,
        }}
      >
        <View style={{ flex: 4 }}>
          <TextInput placeholder="Type Message ....." />
        </View>
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Ionicons name="md-send" size={30} color="#0af" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

> use npm i react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view --save
> import react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view

and then ..

```
<KeyboardAwareScrollView
       contentContainerStyle={{
         height: Dimensions.get("window").height * 2.25,
          width: '100%'
           }}
          >
```

> you can change *2.25 to change height

Answer (score 0):

add behavior="padding" and enabled in KeyboardAvoidingView like this

```html
<KeyboardAvoidingView style={{ flex: 1 }} behavior="padding" enabled>
    <TextInput />
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```