# React native keyboard ignores padding and don't scroll all the way down when input pressed

Tags: css, react-native, react-navigation

Okay, so I have a problem where when I press the text input to add a user the app dont scroll all the way down as you can se in the second picture. I have some padding on the input View wrapper "the red color" but when I press the input it scrolls all the way to input and removes some of the border color and it just looks ugly.

How do I fix so that it scroll all the way down with the padding?

My code for the file

*CSS*

```
  logoWrapper: {
    position: 'relative',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: '100%',
    height: 120
  },
  logo: {
    color: 'white',
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 55,
    fontFamily: 'JosefinSans-BoldItalic',
    position: 'absolute',
    zIndex: 2,
  },
  back: {
    color: 'black',
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 55,
    fontFamily: 'JosefinSans-BoldItalic',
    position: 'absolute',
    top: '50%',
    transform: [{ translateY: -50 }],
    marginTop: 20,
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#303030',
  },
  taskWrapper: {
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
  },
  textSection: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  items: {
    marginTop: 30,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  writeTaskWrapper: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    paddingVertical: 20,
    width: '100%',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  addText: {
    fontFamily: 'JosefinSans-Regular',
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 40,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: -5,
  },
  addPlayer: {
    fontFamily: 'JosefinSans-Regular',
    fontSize: 13,
    color: 'white'
  },
  input: {
    paddingVertical: 15,
    width: 200,
    paddingHorizontal: 25,
    backgroundColor: '#333',
    borderRadius: 60,
    borderColor: '#C0C0C0',
    borderWidth: 1,
    color: 'white',
    height: 60,
  },
  addWrapper: {
    width: 60,
    height: 60,
    backgroundColor: '#333',
    borderRadius: 60,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderColor: '#C0C0C0',
    color: 'white',
    borderWidth: 1,
  },
  startWrapper: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  startButton: {
    padding: 15,
    backgroundColor: '#f06e6e',
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderColor: 'white',
    borderWidth: 2,
    marginTop: 20,
    width: 250,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  startText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 20,
    fontFamily: 'JosefinSans-BoldItalic',
  },
  changeLang: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 10,
    right: 10,
    zIndex: 10,
  },
  langStyle: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 12,
    fontFamily: 'JosefinSans-BoldItalic',
    borderRadius: 10,
    textTransform: 'capitalize',
  },
  debug: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 10,
    left: 10,
    zIndex: 10,
  }
```

*APP js file*

```
  return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.changeLang}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => changeLang()}>
            <Text style={styles.langStyle}>{lang.lang}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <ScrollView style={styles.container} keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'handled'} enableAutoAutomaticScroll={false}>
          <FadeInView>
            <View style={styles.logoWrapper}>
              <Text style={styles.logo}>
                PartyTime
              </Text>
              <Text style={styles.back}>
                PartyTime
              </Text>
            </View>
          </FadeInView>
          <View style={styles.taskWrapper}>
            <View style={styles.startWrapper}>
              {players.length > 0 ? <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => startGame()} style={styles.startButton}>
                <Text style={styles.startText}>Start game</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity> : <Text style={styles.addPlayer}>Add a player to start the game</Text>}
            </View>
            <View style={styles.items}>
              {
                players.map((item, index) => {
                  return (
                    <TouchableOpacity key={index} onPress={() => dispatch(removePlayer(index))}>
                      <Users text={item} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  )

                })
              }
              <View style={styles.writeTaskWrapper}>
                <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder={'Add a player'} placeholderTextColor="white"
                  value={playerName} onChangeText={text => setPlayerName(text)} />
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { dispatch(addPlayer(playerName)); setPlayerName('') }} >
                  <View style={styles.addWrapper}>
                    <Text style={styles.addText}>+</Text>
                  </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
  );
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you find the fix for this?

Comment: same problem, any solution?

Comment: basebase answer worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54547794/how-to-set-the-textinput-box-above-the-keyboard-while-entering-the-input-field-i/54963543#54963543

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using KeyboardAvoidingView.

It would help you scroll the screen when the keyboard events occur.

Official Document :
https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboardavoidingview

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
<KeyboardAwareScrollView  keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'always'}
        style={{flex:1}}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
    {/* Your code goes here*/}
</KeyboardAwareScrollView>
```

Comment: Still dont work. It just pushes the keyboard to the edge of the input just like the second picture shows :/

Comment: I think it's deliberate. It scrolls you down just till the input field is right above the keyboard.